# Query user in Django

Tags: python, django

first post here. Im trying to query the user so i from the form so i can save the user in my database.
This is my code

```
    form = lageBruker(request.POST)
    bruker = User.objects.create(format(request.POST['username']))
    print()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            fornavn = request.POST['first_name']
            etternavn = request.POST['last_name']
            email = request.POST['email']

            kunde = Kunde.objects.create(
                        #bruker = bruker,
                        fornavn=fornavn,
                        etternavn=etternavn,
                        email=email
                    )
            kunde.save()

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'ebutikk/registrer.html', context)
```

Kunde Model:

```
class Kunde(models.Model):
   bruker = models.OneToOneField(
       User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   fornavn = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   etternavn = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):

       return self.etternavn
```

What im trying to do is, when the registration form is submittet, i want to save the registerd user as a kunde/customer. I dont have a User model, i use the default made by django with the import:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I make the form by importing the user creation form given by django and customizing it im my forms.py file.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class lageBruker(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                    'email',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'password1',
                    'password2']
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Im trying to create the a user with the username that i get from the POST request. I have registration form on mye ecommerce website where i want to connect every user that is created to a customer model. I have a customer model in my models.py that has a one to one relationship with a user.

Comment: But the problem is?

Comment: Thats the problem, i cant connect the user to a cutsomer model. Ive tried to make the create the user first, than connect it to the customer model, but is giving me this error:
create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Can you post your `User` , `Kunde` model as well as `format` function.

Comment: Done, tried to explain a little more.

Comment: You have to create `User` model as `User.objects.create(username=request.POST['username'])`

Comment: @hardik24 No you don't. The entire setup is lacking... Quickfixes won't do here.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you duplicate information on the Kunde model that is already on the user? You can just create properties for them if you need a short cut, but from what you're showing the entire Kunde model is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you'd simply create the Kunde model like this:

```py
class Kunde(models.Model):
   bruker = models.OneToOneField(
       User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # more fields here, so the model makes sense

   @property
   def fornavn(self): return self.user.first_name
   @property
   def etternavn(self): return self.user.last_name
   @property
   def email(self): return self.user.email
```

Then all you need to do is:

```py
def customer_signup_view(self, request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = lageBruker(request.POST)
        # Saving the model form returns the user created
        user = form.save()
        # Now use that user to create a new customer
        Kunde.objects.create(user=user)
        return redirect("success/")

    return render(request, 'ebutikk/registrer.html', {"form": lageBruker())
```

Comment: That worked, but im wondering why you wrote lageBruker() instead of form, is there any difference?

Comment: Because I created the variable "form" in the if branch so it's out of scope. Your original code creates it before the if branch, which can also be done.